# Run a php file in a specified timeframe

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script, let's say `fetch.php` which will pull data from other database and insert those data to another database, How do I run the script automatically maybe via command line, let's say I want it to run Everyday at 3pm? Something like a cron.

Comment: Not something like a cron... Exactly that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the cron rule you should add:

```
00 15 * * * php fetch.php
```

Read more here: [Running a script every day using a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382718/running-a-script-everyday-using-a-cronjob)

---

If you are on Windows, you can make use of Windows Task Scheduler.
Here is the link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @JoeneFloresca No, however I just updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: What program should I run in the windows task scheduler?

Comment: Already done it :) Thanks for the idea, basically I made a bat file that will run the script and run that file bat file via task scheduler. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using php from command line is not that hard. Start the `fetch.php` file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// You have the command line arguments available as
$scriptName = $argv[0];
$firstArg = $argv[1];

// Add PHP code here :)

// If an error occurs, exit the script with an error code:
if($someError) exit(1);
```

After saving, set execution rights:

`$ chmod 755 fetch.php`

Then add the script to the crontab. There are many ways, control panels like Plesk and cPanel have a web interface for example, but here's the command line version:

`$ crontab -e`

Add to the file:

`0 15 * * * /path/to/fetch.php`

Save, and you're done.